# how to get Token values when using spark load data from cassandra?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

i use the following code to load data from cassandra:

```
val ts = spark
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("table" -> "t1", "keyspace" -> "keys"))
      .load()
```

so, i can get all the columns,

now, I want to get the token at same time,

i know in cql we can write cql as "`SELECT k,o, TOKEN(k) as t FROM keys.t1`"

the question is how can i get the token in spark?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connector.withSessionDo { session =>
      val res = session.execute("SELECT k,o,token(k) as t FROM keys.t1")
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      for (row <- res) {
        println(row.getLong("t"))
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Spark syntax. But you must be getting the resultSet after executing the query.

Suppose your query is something like,
`select token(<partitionKey(s)>) as fetched_token, column1, column2 from <table_name>`.

While iterating through the rows from resultSet, you may get the token value like `row.getLong("fetched_token")`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I saw, you have used row.getString method. I think Cassandra drive will throw codac exception as you are mapping bigInt to String. That's the reason I used Long. Please correct me if I'm wrong.